# codeigniter - captcha helper not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

captcha function in controller :

```
public function captcha(){
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $captcha = array(
        'word' => 'Random 123',
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'image_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
        'font_path' => './fonts/LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf',
        'img_width' => '300',
        'img_height' => '50',
        'expiration' => '3600',
    );

    $img = create_captcha($captcha);
    $dataf['image'] = $img['image'];

    $this->load->view('captcha_view', $dataf);
}
```

captcha view file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Enter Captcha</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>Creating CAPTCHA</h3>
    <?php 

        echo $image;
        // echo '<br/>Word: ' .$word;
        // echo '<br/>time: ' .$time;

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't load the captcha image, only the heading 'Creating CAPTCHA'. Also,there are no errors displayed.

I am a newbie to php/codeigniter , please help.

Comment: Could you please print Captcha array??

Comment: Please check your permission for captcha folder . It should be either 666 or 777 .

Comment: Array ( [word] => Random 123 [img_path] => ./captcha/ [image_url] => http://localhost/fapogee/captcha/ [font_path] => ./fonts/LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf [img_width] => 300 [img_height] => 50 [expiration] => 3600 )

Comment: @Drudge I changed the permissions, but the problem persists!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Loading Captcha should be like this

```
$captcha_array = array(
    'name' => 'captcha',
    'class' => 'input_box',
    'color' => 'white',
    'placeholder' => '',
    'id' => 'captcha'
);
echo form_input($captcha_array);
```

And your controller code should also be change as well. You need session help too

[Check this tutorial as well](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-captcha-helper/)

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tried from this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR3ODc0vDvA and it worked completely fine in the video.

Comment: use mine. i have sure about the link. I can only recommended for you is this

Comment: Sure, I'll try it in some time!